# How to add a button to the Elementor Text Editor Widget

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, elementor

I need to add a button to the Elementor Text Editor widget that works like the Bold, Italic, Underline buttons. I need to add a `<span class="numbers">[highlighted text here]</span>`.

While the Elementor documentation says the widget uses the TinyMCE editor, the customization method shown on the page below didn't work for me: https://1stwebdesigner.com/how-to-add-custom-buttons-to-the-wordpress-tinymce-editor/

Is there a way to modify the widget using the functions.php file or do I need to create a custom text editor widget to get this functionality?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, then one option would be to create a custom class with custom styling you can add under wordpress -> Customize -> Add Css.

For example you want the class name to be "special-btn". Then you will go and style the class how you want and add it in the Customize -> Add Css. The code can be something like this.

```
.special-btn {
   padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
   color: white;
   background-color: red;
   border: solid 2px pink;
   text-decoration: bold;
}
```

In the widget you will just give the anchor tag the class of "special-btn" which will show it as a button in front end, thanks to the styling you did.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I was looking for. I understand how to create the CSS for a button.

What I need to do is add a button to the editor so I can highlight a piece of text in the editor, click the button and have it add a SPAN around the highlighted text in the same way the Bold, Italics, and Underline buttons do.